# Proof a map is injection

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\gamma:[0;1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be regular Jordan curve. Consider $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, definition a continuous map

$$\Gamma:[0,1]\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}^2, (t,s)\mapsto\gamma(t)+sN(t).$$

Proof where $\epsilon$ enough small, $\Gamma$ is injection and homeomorphic to the image.

Here, $T(t)=\gamma^{'} / \Vert\gamma^{'}\Vert$ and $N(t)=J.T(t)$ where $J=\begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$

To proof $\Gamma$ is injection, I consider $(t_1,s_1),(t_2,s_2)$. Suppose $\Gamma(t_1,s_1)=\Gamma(t_2,s_2)$.

Is the way right? By the way, i don't prove $\Gamma$ is injection.

And why $\Gamma$ is homeomorphic to image??

Comment: What is $N(t)$? Is $N(t) = \gamma'/\| \gamma' \|$?

Comment: $T(t)=\gamma^{'} / \Vert\gamma^{'}\Vert$ and $N(t)=J.T(t)$